# How Do I remove last comma from string in php

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to remove the last comma from below array.

```
{"location":"Park Town,Chennai,Tamil Nadu" }, 
{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" },
```

Comment: Why does it look like you're manually trying to generate JSON... please provide your PHP code.

Comment: Easy way : `$string = str_replace(',]', ']', $yourString);`

Comment: Use Trim function of PHP
$ab = '{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" },';
echo trim($ab,',');

Comment: @Priyank I am using foreach loop every time comma is getting appended how can i remove from last record

Comment: add your full code here

Comment: @Priyank  how can we remove last comma from last  {"location":"Park Town,Chennai,Tamil Nadu" },{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" },

Comment: As i  told you earlier you can remove last comma using trim function 
$db = ' {"location":"Park Town,Chennai,Tamil Nadu" },{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" },';
echo trim($db,',');

Answer (score 1):

Jon Stirling have  right in his  comment. If you try to create json manually - it's bad idea.

But  anwser to your  question  should be something like this (didn't  test it) :

```
<?php
$tab=explode(",",$string);
array_pop($tab);
$string=implode(",",$tab).']';
?>
```

Comment: Hi it's returning same thing  my actual output is  ->  {"location":"Park Town,Chennai,Tamil Nadu" },{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" },   this after that I am passing this on my view page google map  inside array then it becomes like this   [{"location":"Park Town,Chennai,Tamil Nadu" },{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" },]

Comment: https://gist.github.com/poznet/e5b7857855f6366dcc6b65bf3ddbf031   gives  me back   string  without last comma

Comment: {"location":"Park Town,Chennai,Tamil Nadu" }]{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" }] returning like this

Comment: can we remove the last comma from this string    {"location":"Park Town,Chennai,Tamil Nadu" },{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" },

Comment: send whole  php  code where you  generate  this string

Answer (score 0):

Just use php [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function on the string you will get your result.

like below

```
<?php 

$text = '{"location":"Park Town,Chennai,Tamil Nadu" },{"location":"Arajar Salai,Simmakkal,Madurai" },';


$test = rtrim($text,',');
echo $test;
?>
```

A live example https://eval.in/849038

Comment: location is not static , location is generating dynamically right now two record is appearing after some time 3 or 4 records will appear

Comment: OK. That's not a problem. We can trim the last comma after formation of your string that is outside of your loop.